# How to make SalePrice as a discrete value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, discrete-mathematics, binning, continuous

The target variable, `Saleprice` originally is a `continuous` value. I calculated `feature importance` on the other variables except Saleprice and got a ranking of the features.

My teacher said that I do not allow the target variable, Saleprice to be explored as the other variables. As Independent variable is used to predict SalePrice which is the target variable. Target variable can be treated as a dependent variable because it depends on the independent variables.

She suggested to use I can explore Saleprice because it is a continuous variable to `binning method`, for example binning Saleprice from 100k to 150k . The range can be regarded as a single value. (treated as a discrete value)

`May I know how should I apply the binning method on Saleprice to make it as a discrete variable?`

and

`how does that being a discrete variable can help me better in building of model and prediction of Saleprice?`

[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data) I just use the train data only.

Answer (score 0):

Binning help in reducing noise and non-linearity in data. It's hard for the model to find a relation for age data say **(5,7,11,3,19,2,17)** as compare to age **(5,10,15,20)**.

Binning allows easy identification of outliers, invalid and missing values of numerical variables.

for more depth and type of binning implementation try this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-binning-or-discretization/